# mariabackup restoring a single database without affecting other tables

Tags: database, centos, mariadb, database-backups

I'm currently using MariaDB 10.3.17 on CentOS 8 and I'm trying to restore a backup of a specific database. I made 2 dummy databases named **test** and **test_restore**. I updated **test_restore** then created an incremental backup with `--databases="mysql test_restore"`

I ran:

```
# mariabackup --prepare --target-dir=<dir>/mariadb/backup/2020-02/18_10h_full/

# mariabackup --prepare --target-dir=<dir>/mariadb/backup/2020-02/18_10h_full/ --incremental-dir=<dir>/mariadb/backup/2020-02/18_10h10m_inc/

# mariabackup --copy-back --target-dir=<dir>/mariadb/backup/2020-02/18_10h_full/
```

After that, I lost all data on my **test** db but kept my updated **test_restore** db

I can do a full backup and restore with the incremental back up of ALL databases altogether but thats gonna take a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but this may people others. I found a way to automate the process the blog talks about, the blog is fine for small schemas but if you have hundreds of tables it would take hours for you to do.

Hope this helps someone

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/individual-database-restores-with-mariabackup-from-full-backup/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34862019)

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but MariaDB's blog article [How to Restore a Single Database from MariaDB Backup](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/how-to-restore-a-single-database-from-mariadb-backup/) seems very suitable here. I'm linking it, because it doesn't make sense to me to simply copy all of the instructions and hints.